# Independent and exclusive for events

Tags: probability, independence

In probability theory, I now understand that 'two events are independent' does not mean that 'two events are exclusive' and vice versa.

Now I wonder if the former means the latter is not true, or the latter means the former is not true.

Comment: If two events $A,B$ are mutually exclusive then $P(A\cap B)=0$. So there will be independence as well if and only if $P(A)P(B)=0$ (i.e. at least one of them has probability zero). This is not impossible.